# Why the jaggedness at the end? How to fix the CSS style

Tags: html, css, layout

Here is my stylesheet http://jsfiddle.net/t0yo0v84/ there are several problems but the most pressing one is the jaggedness at the edges on the right end.

As can be seen in the jsfiddle the right side of the content's background-color is not covering the whole space perfectly till the boundary. What cause that ?
Here is my CSS. I need to have the table in the page its a must. Both the tables are required.

```
html, body {
    min-width :100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin : 0.3em;
    border-style : solid;
    border-width : 0.18em;
    border-color : black;
    overflow-x : scroll;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.middle {
    background-color:green;
    height:100%;
}
.middle.row{
  overflow-x: auto; 
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.bottom {
    background-color:rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.85);
    color : #FFF;
}
.top {
    background-color:pink;
}
.left {
    width:20%;
    background:#FFD540;
    height:100%;
}
.right {
    width: 78%;
    background:#E4E4E4;
    height:100%;
}

.top.row {
   height : 3%;
   width : 100%;
   margin : 2em;
   background-color : #F6F6F6;
}
.bottom.row {
   height : 20%;
   width : 100%;
   text-align :center;
}
.row > .cell{
  width : 100%;
}
.cell > #logo {
  position : relative;
  width : 22%;
  float : left;
  margin-left : 10px;
  margin-top : 15px;

}

.cell > #heading {
   width : 75%;
   text-align : center;
   float : left;
}
.banner {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: black;
    font-family : Raleway;
    line-height: 0.9;
}
img {
  max-width : 100%;
  height : auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


#data-table tr : first-child {
    background-color : lightgrey;
}
#top-table tr:first-child{
     background-color : lightgrey;
}
.tableInPage{
  overflow: auto;
}
#top-table {
   margin-top : 20px;
   margin-left : 10px;
}
#data-table {
   margin-top : 20px;
   margin-left : 10px;
}

#user-div {
   float : left;
   width : 22%;
   font-family : Raleway;
}
#acc-type-heading {
   float : left;
   width: 75%;
   font-family : Raleway;
}

.upper  {
   background-color:rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.85);
    color : #FFF;
    height :
}
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

#data-table tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: lightblue; 
}
th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}
#data-table-container{
   width : 1260px!important;
   overflow-x : scroll;
}
.menu-items {
  margin-left : 25px;
  margin-top : 70px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

What causes that and how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0yo0v84/1/) might help you. Instead of using `margin` on the tables, remove it and use `padding` on the parent element which holds the two tables

Comment: A better approach to allocating space between the div parent and any children. +1

Answer (score 1):

Because in your CSS code you have to remove the margin-left of both:

```
#top-table {
    margin-top : 20px;
    /*margin-left : 10px;*/
}
#data-table {
    margin-top : 20px;
    /*margin-left : 10px;*/
}
```

If you remove the margin-left, you will see that the background is what I think what you want.

Comment: Either this or you go change the style of the even **tr** elements, just like you changed it for the odd ones. It's not the actual background of the row which is white.

Answer (score 1):

The `<td>` elements are being pushed 10px over by `margin-left:10px` in the `#data-table` and `#top-table` css rules. This can be fixed by:

```
#data-table, #top-table {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px; 
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the left margin just give every even row `background-color:grey;` with

```
#data-table tr  {
  background-color : lightgrey;
}
#top-table tr{
  background-color : lightgrey;
}
```